sObject type CollaborationGroup is not replicable
When performing the following GET request
/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/CollaborationGroup/updated/?start=[date]&end=[date]

I'm getting the following error:
sObject type CollaborationGroup is not replicable

That works with User. Why not CollaborationGroup? What should I do to get updated ids?

Not all objects are replicateable as the doc tells you. What are you trying to accomplish? Please edit your question.

I'm trying to replicate the objects into a different system, which is not Salesforce. Both User and CollaborationGroupMember have replicateable set to true, but not CollaborationGroup. Any way to change that?

Hmm, maybe I can just collect the group ids from the members.
